# WAMP not working on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, localhost, wamp

I just installed the latest WAMP on windows 7 64bit. The installation was successful but now WAMP doesn't open. It says 'Aestan Tray Menu has stopped working' and when I click on 'Close Program' it shows the error 'Exception Exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15A0. Could not execute run action: . '

Please tell me how can I fix this.

Comment: get cause and best answer: http://hints.steptoinstall.com/aestan-tray-menu-has-stopped-working.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether you have installed 32 bit or 64 bit version of WAMP.  Reference [this](http://nikunj-solutions.blogspot.com/2011/08/exception-in-module-wampmanagerexe-at.html)

1. Install the 64-bit Windows OS and keep the WAMP Server's 64-bit installation as it is. --OR--
2. Install the 32-bit version of WAMP Server on the current Windows 32-bit OS.

Secondly, If you have installed correct version then follow this [link](http://drupal.org/node/1338808) the will clear much about this issue.

You need the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29 (x86)
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15336 (x64)

Answer (score 0):

The error with exception 000F15A0 means caused by the windows runtime . So, install the Visual C++ 2008 runtime and run the wamp. The error will be gone.